# What does addEventListener e=> mean?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn the base of this code, but I don't understand the meaning of the e=>. I guess that it's some kind of a shortcut, and I've done some research and didn't find anything. I want to make the most out of this code. So can you help me, or at least not devote?
What is this syntax?

```js
const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzslEnJtPfNT6z0ohrXP9cZYGhWvKVsFjQV7eLcriT3tok5D5ty/exec'
const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
  .then($("#form").trigger("reset"))
  .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
})
```

Comment: event object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
e => {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

is equivalent to

```
function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

...
In this specific example

```
form.addEventListener('submit', e => { e.preventDefault(); ... });
```

e is the eventObject, which the event was triggered by.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', eventObj => { eventObj.preventDefault(); ... });
```

Comment: And why there are no ";" after each line?

Comment: ; is optional. Better to have though

Comment: There are cases where you have to put ;?

Comment: JavaScript will insert them for you if they don’t exist. It is good practice to have semi-colon

Comment: Can someone break the fetch line for its components? because I don't understand a thing.

Comment: You have to learn from the basics properly.

fetch(URL, {method, body})
.then()
.catch();

This is a concept called Promise. You will have ";" only at the last line. Having ";" above would throw an error.

Please do some search on Promise

Answer (score 1):

This is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
e => {}
```

is the the es6 way of declaring functions/closures.

In most cases it can be used interchangeably with:

```
function(e){}
```

**But there are some differences**, mainly with the [lack of binding](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26) to `this`, so use with caution if you are expecting them to work in the same way when using `this` in your functions (ie: prototype functions).

Comment: Thank you! and e is a short for event?

Comment: you bet it is :)